# Ruby cannot load such file mac MLion

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install gems in ruby because I'm following beginning ruby book, and I need to  install redcloth when I install it on terminal it appears to install but when I change to irb this happens

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > require 'rubygems'
 => false 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > require 'RedCloth'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- RedCloth
    from /Users/AlbertoRdz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/AlbertoRdz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/AlbertoRdz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

also in terminal

```
MacBook-de-Jesus:rubygems-1.8.24 AlbertoRdz$ which redcloth
/Users/AlbertoRdz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/redcloth
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix it as following:

`require 'redcloth'`